# insert array value in database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I need to insert array value into table I have the forms which has array value.Now return only first character of an array 's' need to print 'sample1'

```
<input type="text"  placeholder="First Name" name="first_name[]"/>
<input type="text"  placeholder="Last Name" name="last_name[]">
<input type="text"  placeholder="Age" name="age[]">
```

codeigniter code

```
   $fname=$this->input->post('first_name');
   foreach($fname as $name){
       $n=$name['first_name']; //return only first character
     }
```

```
  print_r($fname) return an array
    Array ( [0] => sample1 [1] => sample2 )
```

Comment: Your form names are arrays, if you want only a singular value, remove the [] from them, and don't foreach the post value.

Comment: What is your desired result ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use like this :

```
foreach($fname as $name){
       $n=$name;
     }
```

**Edit :**

```
$fname=$this->input->post('first_name');
for($i=0;$i<count($fname);$i++) {
    echo $fname[$i];
}
```

Comment: I need to get 2nd value from the array i.e) sample2

Comment: Then simple use `$fname[1]`. No need for `foreach`.

Comment: can you please give example

Comment: `$fname=$this->input->post('first_name'); echo$fname[1];`

Comment: for($i=0;$i<($a-1);$i++)
   {
   echo $i;
     $person = array(
   
   'firstName'   => $fname[$i], 
   'lastName'          => $lname[$i]
   
   );
   
  }

Comment: above code not working with $i can you please guide me

Comment: Please see my updated answer if you want to use it with `for`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104413/discussion-between-user3386779-and-mr-engineer).

Answer (score 3):

change foreach like this

```
   foreach($fname as $name){
   $n=$name; //return only first character
 }
```

this working fine

OR
You store all data (first_name) single cell
try this

example: sample1,sample2

```
 $first_names= implode(",",$fname);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this:

```
foreach($this->input->post("first_name") as $name){
    $n=$name;
}
```

No need to assign post data to a variable.